# Find all bipartite graphs of diameter 2.

Tags: graph-theory

This problem I have taken from the book "Exercises
in Graph Theory". Hint is given at the end of the book. The hint is "$K_{m,n}$,  $m, n \geq 1$, $m + n\geq 3$.Demonstrate that after the deletion of
any edge $e = uv$ from $K_{m,n}$, either $d(u, v) = 3$ in the resulting graph or it
becomes disconnected."
But I don't understand This hint.  Please help me for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete an edge from a graph with vertices $u$ and $v$, then the distance between them never decreases: in the best case it remains the same, but it can increase as well. Of course, the same can be said about the diameter of the graph.

It turns out that very bipartite graph $H$ can be seen as a complete bipartite graph with an appropiate set of edges deleted. So, if we remove the edges one by one, the diameter of the resulting graphs range from $2$ (which is the diameter of the complete bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$ if at least one of $n, m$ is greater than $1$) to the diameter of $H$, and the resulting sequence of "diameters" is never decreasing. So, for every bipartite graph, its diameter is at least $2$.

The hint asks you to show that this "diameter increase" happens at the very first step: the diameter is at least three even if you remove only one edge.